# tmux errors: The command could not be located because '/bin:/usr/bin' is not included in the PATH environment variable

Tags: tmux, path

When I run `$tmux` and open an instance of a tmux session and try to run a command such as `ls` I receive the following error:

```
∆ ls
Command 'ls' is available in the following places
 * /bin/ls
 * /usr/bin/ls
The command could not be located because '/usr/bin:/bin' is not included in the PATH environment variable.

ls: command not found
```

Answer (score 1):

Check your PATH before and after invoking tmux

```
echo $PATH
```

Then check your `~/.bash_profile`. There must be something there that is overriding your current `$PATH`.

Comment: It's more likely `.tmux.conf` that's overwriting `$PATH` - otherwise, `bash` alone would have the same problem.

Comment: not in tmux `echo $PATH:  /home/kcrum/.local/bin:/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin:/usr/games:/usr/local/games:/snap/bin`

in tmux `echo $PATH:   /home/kcrum/.local/bin`

Comment: so I found in my .bash_profile I had `export PATH="/home/kcrum/.local/bin"`
After getting rid of the line it startef to work.  Im curious if it was never a problem before because previously my shell would only source .bashrc